# Unrecognized locale "jp" exception in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to make my website multilingual and i am using YII.
I have made three links 'english','chinese' and 'japanese' which when clicked executes this function

```
public function actionChangelangs($lang)
        {

              if($lang=='ch')
            {
                Yii::app()->session['_lang']='ch';

            }
            elseif($lang=='jp')
            {
                Yii::app()->session['_lang']='jp';

            }
            else
            {
                Yii::app()->session['_lang']='en_us';

            } 
           $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl); 

        }
```

But i am getting error like `Unrecognized locale "jp".`

O do not know what it is and how to solve it. I am fed up of finding the solution but all in vain. PLease help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the proper language code is "ja", not "jp". See the [framework/messages](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/tree/1.1.14/framework/messages) folder.

Comment: because chinese is zh.

Comment: That should really be "zh_cn" or "zh_tw".

Answer (score 1):

you are providing wrong locale code that's way you are getting error `Unrecognized locale "jp".`

- Japanese --> ja
- Chinese --> ch
- english - us --> en-us

reefer locale code properly here [Locale code for all country](http://www.science.co.il/Language/Locale-codes.asp)

hope it may help you